# Difference between Task ID vs Message ID vs Stream ID in Storm? And how "anchoring tuples" and "acker tasks" are related to the context?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to know the difference among them, and how they are related to each other, and what are the roles of "anchoring tuples" and "acker tasks". If possible, please with detailed explanation and examples. I have read the official documentation and some related articles, but I have unclear understanding on this topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**StreamID**: per default there is a single (logical) stream called `default`. In some use-cases it is necessary, to have not a single (logical) stream but multiple (with different data in each stream). For that you can declare other stream and assign an ID (ie, name) to them to distinguish them (this is done in the `declareOutputFields(...)` method). When "plugging" your topology together, per default, you always assign to the default stream (as input stream), but you can also specify the name of the stream you want to receive explicitly.

**TaskID**. each Spout/Bolt has an assigned parallelism (ie, degree of parallelism, `dop`). Thus, each Spout/Bolt is executed in multiple tasks, and each task get an ID assigned such that they can be distinguished.

**MessageID**: if you want to use fault-tolerance mechanism, you need to assign a unique ID to each tuple that is emitted by Spouts.

**Acker tasks**: those are used to process `ack` messages from your bolts (ie, message that are sent by the system when you call `collector.ack(...)` or `collector.fail(...)`) to track if tuples are processed successfully or fail. You don't need to care about them usually.

**Anchoring**: anchoring is a mechanism to tell Storm, which input tuples are used to produce which output tuples. If you have for example a Bolt, that splits a sentence into words and emits a tuple per word, you would anchor all words to the same sentence. (If on of the word tuples fail, Storm know that it need to reply the sentence tuple such that the lost tuple can be recovered). On the other hand, if you aggregate let's say the last 5 input tuples to compute an average value, you would buffer all 5 input tuples until you emit the average tuple and use all 5 input tuple as anchors for this single avg output tuple. (Again, if the output tuple is lost, Storm know that it need to reply all 5 input tuples such that the lost average tuple can be recomputed). Be aware, that you cannot use tuples as anchors, that are already acked to Storm. Thus, you need to delay acking an input tuple, until it is no longer needed as an anchor tuple.

Comment: thank you for the answer, good answer, and it would be great if you can provide some example usages

Comment: Concepts and examples at the bottom of the page: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2016/05/more-concepts-of-apache-storm-you-need.html